# Evaluating an integral without knowing the explicit form of numerator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $D\in C^1([0,1])$ and $D(0)=0$, $D(u)>0\,\,\forall\,\,u\in (0,1]$.

Let $\phi_0\in (0,1)$, calculate the integral
$$\int_{\phi_0}^1\frac{D(\phi)}{-\alpha(1-\phi)}\,d\phi$$

It is known the answer is $-\infty$, but I cannot justify in a rigorous way except I know the problem may come from $\ln|1-\phi|$ at 1...

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

$D(1)=c>0$, and there is a $\delta>0$ with $|D(x)-D(1)|<c/2$ when $1-x<\delta$, so $D(x)>c/2$ in this region.  Let $\delta_1=\min(\delta,1-\phi_0)$, and let $\delta_2=\delta_1\exp(-N)$.  So
$$ \int_{\phi_0}^1\frac{D(\phi)}{1-\phi}d\phi>\int_{1-\delta_1}^{1-\delta_2}\frac{c/2}{1-\phi}d\phi=Nc/2$$

Comment: How can you tell $D(1)=c$, $D$ does not need to be assumed bounded here...

Comment: You are given $D(u)>0\forall u\in(0,1]$, and $1\in(0,1]$

Comment: yes, i did, so $D(1)>0$ is known. But couldn't $D(1)$ be unbounded?

Comment: You are given $D\in C([0,1])$, so it is continuous on a closed interval, so it is bounded.  Although, no, you don't need it to be bounded for this proof, just greater than a finite number $c$.

Comment: yes you are right. "just greater than a finite number" will do. But on your comment, continuous function on a closed interval is bounded. Where can I find this result, though I know it is from elementary real analysis...

Comment: Sorry, not off the top of my head.

Comment: I think it is the "bounded theorem"...continuous function on a closed interval must attain its maximum and minimum at least once.

Comment: There's a nice proof of this in Chapter 3 (I think) of Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, along with a proof of the intermediate value theorem and the fact that a continuous function on a closed interval assumes its max and min. The chapter is called "Three Hard Theorems," but they're only hard if you're taking your first calculus course.

Answer (score 0):

Let's show that:

$$\left|\int_{\Phi_0}^{1}\frac{D(x)}{1-x}dx\right|>M$$

For any constant $M$.

We know that $D(u)>0$ for $u \in [0,1)$, so $\frac{D(u)}{1-u}>0$ for $u \in [0,1)$, so:

$$\left|\int_{\Phi_0}^{1}\frac{D(x)}{1-x}dx\right|=\int_{\Phi_0}^{1}\frac{D(x)}{1-x}dx$$

We also know that $D(1)=2\varepsilon>0$, so there exists $\delta$, that $D(u)>\varepsilon$ for $u \in [1-\delta,1)$, so:

$$\int_{\Phi_0}^{1}\frac{D(x)}{1-x}dx \geq \int_{1-\delta}^{1}\frac{D(x)}{1-x}dx>\int_{1-\delta}^{1}\frac{\varepsilon}{1-x}dx=\infty$$